# Can somebody show me a proof for this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Equation of the Volume of a Cone:

> $$\mathbf{V}=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$$

Taking the Derivative in perspective to time because the radii, and height are either decreasing or increasing:

> $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\pi}{3}[2rh\frac{dr}{dt}+r^2\frac{dh}{dt}]$$

I understand how to take the derivative of it and all, moreover, I am lost on how to prove this a different way because I have seen it done one way substituting $r$ and $h$ for $r(t)$ and $h(t)$ but do not know any other to prove it.

Is there another way to do it, and can somebody please show me?

Comment: How to prove what? You said you can do the derivative.

Comment: I think you forgot an $h$: $\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi[2r\frac{dr}{dt}\color{red}{h}+r^2\frac{dh}{dt}]$

Comment: @Beta How to arrive at the same conclusion.  I am probably just over thinking it.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I just noticed.

Comment: The volume of a cone should have a $\frac{1}{3}$ in it: $V = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$.

Comment: @John Barber You are right ; there is a confusion :  $\pi r^2 h$ is the volume of a cylinder of height $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function in two variable, essentially.

$$V(r, h) = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$$

So when differentiation with respect to time, you have to use the chain rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}r}\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}t} + \frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}h}\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}t}$$

$$\frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}r} = \frac{2}{3}\pi r h$$
$$\frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}h} = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2$$

Hence

$$\frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}r}\frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}t} + \frac{\text{d}{V}}{\text{d}h}\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}t} = $$ $$ = 2\pi r h \frac{\text{d}r}{\text{d}t} + \pi r^2 \frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}t} = $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{3}\left[\text{what you have written above}\right]$$

**P.s.**

It's obvious that derivatives are zero if neither $r$ nor $h$ depend on time. That is as obvious as useless to remark but who knows.

Comment: Voila! some one did vote down without leaving a proper comment. Why?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Indeed! I don't know why. I had 1 vote and now 0. Well I found out that those idiots often just down vote and then close the page and bye bye. I don't care. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually nothing to prove here, it is simply an application of derivatives. However there are some assumptions so let's look carefully at what is happening here.

We have the equation for the volume,
$$
V =\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h,
$$
and we are told that both $r$ and $h$ are changing in time. Therefore writing $r = r(t)$ and $h=h(t)$ is only making it clearer what is said in the question (you should read "r changes in time" as saying "r is a function of time"). Then differentiating follows by simply applying the chain rule.

But importantly this formula applies when we know that $r$ and $h$ change in time. If they didn't then we would not formulate it this way necessarily since if they don't depend on time the derivatives would be zero.

Comment: Thanks but that is the method I already knew.

Comment: What we are all pointing out is that there aren't different 'proofs' here, this is about understanding what the derivative means in the problem you are considering. If that seems a bit cryptic then please ask and I/others will try to elaborate.

Comment: +1 for indicating (1) that there aren't different 'proofs'; and (2) the question is just a simple application of the chain rule.